# OpenLayers is showing 720 degree around the globe

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers

My current OpenLayers looks like the following:
[a wrong map http://i1179.photobucket.com/albums/x384/yoyomyo/Picture2.png](http://i1179.photobucket.com/albums/x384/yoyomyo/Picture2.png)

It has twice as many continents as there should be.

I was trying to set Bounds to my map, but the entire map just refuses to render:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -90, 180, 90)});

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");

map.addLayers([layer]);

map.setCenter(
    new OpenLayers.LonLat(-71.147, -42.472).transform( new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject()), 
    12);
```

Does any Map guru know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WrapDateLine](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.wrapDateLine)

Try `wrapDateLine:false`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to set maxExtent.

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SettingZoomLevels

Otherwise I have no clue. :)

Comment: tried {maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -90, 180, 90)}, no luck. I looked at openCycleMap. And their map is not bounded to (-180, -90, 180, 90) either. Is this something that's impossible to fix on OSM?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer with an example to work off of.  I would zoom in 12 is pretty far out.  And yes you can zoom in on OSM http://www.openstreetmap.org/

In that site, they use these values

```
    var centre = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-0.1, 51.5);
    var zoom = 5;

    setMapCenter(centre, zoom); //It calls map.setCenter()
```

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is more with the bounds instead of zoom. I tried to set maxExtent at map initialization but still failed to limit the map.

Comment: To control the user, use [restrictedExtent](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.restrictedExtent)

Comment: To restrict zoom, you may have to set it on the BaseLayer ie. map.baseLayer.restrictedMinZoom = 3;

Answer (score 0):

Okay I give up. I think this is just the way OpenStreetMap displays its map.
I have seen many demos and they are all like the one above.